# Symmetric NAT implementation with incremental source port? (software/OS or hardware router)

Tags: iptables, openwrt, nat

I'm looking for a Symmetric NAT implementation with an incremental source port number. E.g. a client behind the NAT sends a UDP packet to server A using the outbound/source port 1000, and another packet to server B gets the source port 1001, etc..

I have tried different Iptables configurations, but can only setup a Cone NAT (same source port for every destination) or random source ports for each different destination (Masquerade with the --random option).

So, is there a way to configure Iptables to have incremental source port numbers? Or do you know of a software/OS (like OpenWRT) or router hardware that has such a behaviour?

Comment: Did you find a solution?